# Creating file in sandboxed FileSystem on Chrome error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fileapi

Trying to create a file using the sandboxed FileSystem API:

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;     
window.requestFileSystem(
    window.PERSISTENT, 
    1024 * 1024, 
    function( fs ) {       
        fs.root.getFile( 'test.txt', {create: true}, function( fe )
        {
            alert( "OK" );
        }, function( e )
        {
            alert( e.code );
        }
        );
    }, null
);
```

I always get the error code 10 (`QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR`) on this code.

Chrome: `17.0.963.79 m`, started with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *persistent* storage, you have to explicitly ask for permission of the user:

```
webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota( 
  webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT,

  1000, // amount of bytes you need

  function(availableBytes) {
    alert("Quota is available. Quota size: " + availableBytes);
    // you can use the filesystem now
  }
);
```

You can also choose for temporary storage.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful answer by pimvdb. As of now (October 2013) Chrome reports `webkitStorageInfo` as deprecated. Instead, prefer the following:

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(
  2048, //bytes of storage requested
  function(availableBytes) { 
    console.log(availableBytes);
  }
);
```

To request temporary storage, use `navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage.requestQuota`